# Quasar2 Vue3 q-popup-edit @save event never called

Tags: events, popup, vuejs3, quasar-framework, editbox

I have the following template:

```
<template>
  <q-item tag="label" v-ripple>
    <q-popup-edit
      v-model="editedModel"
      @before-show="onFieldClick"
      @save="setValue"
      :cover="false"
      fit
      buttons
    >
      <template v-slot:title>
        <div class="text-mono">{{ name }}</div>
      </template>
      <q-select
        dense
        autofocus
        emit-value
        v-model="editedModel"
        multiple
        :options="options"
        counter
      />
    </q-popup-edit>
    <q-item-section>
      <q-item-label class="text-mono">{{ name }}</q-item-label>
      <q-item-label caption>{{ description }}</q-item-label>
      <q-item-label caption>{{ model }}</q-item-label>
    </q-item-section>
  </q-item>
</template>
```

The `@save` method is never called. What do I miss? Thanks.

Comment: Did you solved? I got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked the following:
I added: **v-slot="scope"**  to the **q-popup-edit**

<q-popup-edit v-model="initialValue" **v-slot="scope"** buttons    @save="save">

and then I replaced my v-model inside q-input to this:

<q-input  **v-model="scope.value"** >